# How to check for the existence of values after splitting in object, and then assign them if only the last one does not exist

Tags: javascript, loops, object

There is a question about sorting and adding an object, more precisely for example:

I have a string `a1/b1/c1/d1` that
`spl = "a1/b1/c1/d1".split ("/")` and at the output I get an array of 4 elements.
I have an object - `obj`, I need to cycle through the `spl` array and each new turn I added values, right now I'll tell you

```
for(var i = 0; i < spl.length(); i++){
    // and here's the code I don't know how to write
}

/* there must be something like this
//if obj[spl[0]] is existing then do
i = 0: obj[spl[0]] = {};

//if obj[spl[0]][spl[1]] is existing then do
i = 1: obj[spl[0]][spl[1]] = {};

//if obj[spl[0]][spl[1]][spl[2]] is existing then do
i = 2: obj[spl[0]][spl[1]][spl[2]] = {};

//and if the last element of the massiv is not existing then do
i = 3: obj[spl[0]][spl[1]][spl[2]][spl[3]] = {};

/if the last element of the massiv is existing then do nothing
the end of the cycle*/
```

that is, each scroll is added as long as `i` is less than the length of the array
it should work like this

```
obj {
    a1:{
        b1:{
            c1:{
                d1:{}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For example, if I have 2 elements in `spl`, the loop will add only 2 times as in the example, if 5, then 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. You can change `path` and comment `var obj = {}`. First, if you want to create `a1` in `obj` you have to change `path` to `a1`. The script will check the path and create it in `obj`. After that. You can add `/b1` to `a1` to create `b1` in `a1` and etc.
If you make a mistake in the path (`var obj = {}` and `var path = 'a1/b1/c1'.split("/");`) the program will output the error. 
`console.log("Wrong path_2");` - (here) `b1` - is not found.
 `console.log("Wrong path_1");` - (here) `a1` - is not found.
In this script I have `var obj = {}` and `path = ["a1","b1"]`. `obj` doesn't have `a1` so console will output 'Wrong path_1' and our `obj`

```js
var path = 'a1/b1'.split("/");
var obj = {};
var addition = "";
var elem_name = "";
for(elem of path){
    if(obj[elem] === undefined && path.length === 1){

        obj[elem] = {};
        console.log(`${elem} have been created`);

    }else if(obj[elem] !== undefined && path.length > 1){

        obj = obj;
        addition = obj[elem];
        elem_name = elem;

    }else if(addition[elem] === undefined && path.length > 1 && addition !== ""){
        if(elem === path[path.length-1]){
            
            addition[elem] = {};
            console.log(`${elem} have been created in ${elem_name}`);
            break;
            
        }else if(elem !== path[path.length-1]){
            console.log("Wrong path_2");
            break;
        }

    }else if(addition[elem] !== undefined && path.length >1){

        obj = obj;
        addition = addition[elem];
        elem_name = elem;
        console.log(`${elem} was created earlier`);
        
    }else if(obj[elem] === undefined && path.length > 1){
        console.log(`Wrong path_1`);
        break;
        
    }else if(obj[elem] !== undefined && path.length === 1){
        console.log(`${elem} was created earlier`);
        break;

    }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, is this what you want to achieve?

```js
let obj = {}
let path = 'a1/a2/a3'.split('/')

let current = obj
for (let prop of path) {
  current[prop] = current[prop] || {}
  current = current[prop]
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Yes and no, you have done only 50% of work. Now you are having `obj = {}` and in the end, you are getting the result. But also you have to check if `obj[a1] !== null`(if true) then check `obj[a1][a2] !== null` (if false) then `break`. In the end if `obj[a1][a2][a3] === null` then `obj[a1][a2][a3] = {}` (in the end if we have not `a3` we have to add this property in `obj` !only the end property!). We have to check our path from `a1` to `a3`. If we don't have any errors of the path to a3 in our `obj` and we don't have the last element `(a3)` in `obj` then add this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let spl = "a1/b1/c1/d1".split ("/")
let obj = {}
let temp = obj
for(let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
  temp[spl[i]] = {}
  temp = temp[spl[i]]
}

console.log(obj)
```

For every iteration, temp is updated. 
So, initially `temp` is obj but in the first iteration `temp["a1"]` is set to an empty object and then temp's value is updated to `temp["a1"]`. At this point again temp is an empty object. And for the next iteration `temp["b1"]` set to an empty object and the loop continues.

Since objects are passed by reference, `obj` is being updated throughout the process which results in the required output format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you really need to check if nested property already exists, because it certainly won't be in an empty object, so I avoided this check.

```js
const buildObjectFromPath = splitter => path => {
  path = path.split(splitter)
  const obj = {}
  let current = obj
  for (const prop of path) {
    current = current[prop] = {}
  }
  return obj
}

const path = 'a1/b1/c1/d1'
console.log(buildObjectFromPath('/')(path))
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduceRight` will simplify as one line

```js
const obj = "a1/a2/a3/a4"
  .split("/")
  .reduceRight((acc, curr) => ({ [curr]: acc }), {});

console.log(obj);
```